# Email through sms is in separate threads

Tags: sms, email, nexus-6p

When I receive an sms from an email address, the name of the thread is something like `0000000000000001`.  If I respond, the person gets it, but then if the person responds to *that*, it comes in a new thread called `0000000000000002`.  The next comes in `0000000000000003`, etc.  I have tried adding the email address as a contact, but each new message still comes in a new thread.  What can I do to stop this?

I am using Silence (the messaging application) on a Nexus 6P on Android 6.0.1

Answer (score 0):

There might be a problem with your message app. 
Unfortunately there is no possibility to get rid of this problem. 
You got a few options to choose:

1. > Go to: Settings > Applications > Manage Applications > Select the Messaging
   >   App
   >
   > Choose 'Clear Data' and also 'Clear Cache'.

**You will lose all data and text messages in your phone.**

2. Try to install another SMS app there are plenty on Google Store. IMO the one of the bests is the Textra. Hope you enjoy it.
3. [Maybe it is connected with an APN issue.](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19310/stock-sms-client-creates-multiple-threads-for-the-same-number?rq=1)
4. [This might help.](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/20897/sms-email-gateway-app?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Google messaging application, you should [file a bug report](https://source.android.com/source/report-bugs.html). As stated in the documentation, search for your bug first before reporting a new bug.

This is a long-term fix; do not expect quick turnaround on bugs getting fixed.

Do not expect others to do bug reporting for you. If no one says anything, the developers may not know there is a problem.

Comment: Actually, I'm using Silence, not the default.  The idea of filing a bug report, however, is a good one.